# Why does yum update says it is "Installing" one of the packages?

Tags: linux, yum, package-managers

When I run `yum update`, it lists the packages that it will upgrade. For one of the packages, `kernel`, it lists it under the "Installing" header. All other packages are listed under the "Upgrading" header. Why does it say that is "Installing" that package? The current version of that package is `4.14.104-95.84.amzn2` and it will be upgraded/installed to `4.14.114-103.97.amzn2`. This is not even a major version change, in which case, it might have made sense. Is there a general case where this happens? Or is this only specific to kernel and related packages, since they are special in a sense?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have posted the question on SuperUser here https://superuser.com/questions/1432948/why-does-yum-update-says-it-is-installing-one-of-the-packages . Please feel free to delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

From here - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8-beta/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/updating-kernel-with-yum_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel

> The yum package manager always installs a new kernel instead of replacing the current one, which could potentially leave your system unbootable.

The system must be rebooted after installing `kernel` package for consistency, integrity reasons.

Also `yum` handles updating the `kernel` package so that end-user need not worry about upgrading or installing it.

Comment: I was advised to move this question to SuperUser. I have posted the question here https://superuser.com/questions/1432948/why-does-yum-update-says-it-is-installing-one-of-the-packages . If you wish, you can repost your answer there, since I did find it helpful. Thank you for answering it.

Comment: sure thanks for the info & tag @euphoria83